# Python counting through a number with >=

Tags: python

I'm learning Python(2.7) at the moment, and an exercise says to write a program which counts how many coins you need to pay a specific sum.
My solution is this:

```
sum = input("Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: ")
coins = []
euro = [20,10,5,2,1,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01]

for i in euro:
    while sum >= i:
        sum -= i
        coins.append(i)

print coins
```

This is nearly working, but when I input e.g. 17,79 it gives me the coins for 17,78.

```
Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: 17.79
[10, 5, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]
```

Why? Has this something to do with round?

Comment: The counter starts at `0` ;)

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: Also, don't use the `float` type to store numbers. It can lead to rounding errors. It is better to store money in cents.

Comment: his/her 'solution' is not correct.

Comment: @Allendar: which counter? Also @Maxi, you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name - it will shadow the builtin.

Comment: "Bitte *gib* einen Euro-Betrag ein:"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For currency calculations it's best to avoid `float` type if you can, because of accumulating rounding errors. You can do it in a way similar to this:

```
amount= input("Bitte gib einen Euro Betrag ein: ")
coins = []
cents = [2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
amount = int(float(amount) * 100)
for cent in cents:
    while amount >= cent:
        amount -= cent
        coins.append(cent)

print [coin / 100.0 for coin in coins]
```

I've also changed the variable name from `sum` to `amount` - `sum` will shadow the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function.

Result:

```
Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: 17.79
[10.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02]
```

Alternatively, you can implement this without inner `while` loop, like this:

```
for cent in cents:
    n = int(math.floor(amount / cent))
    amount -= n * cent
    coins += [cent] * n
```

It's possible to exit loop earlier (`if not amount: break`) and avoid unnecessary operations (`if not n: continue`), but I omitted these guards for readability.

Another possible alternative is to use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) data type.

Answer (score 2):

It has. If after executing the code you check the 'sum' value, you get something like 0,009999999999999133, which IS smaller than the smallest coin.

My suggestion? Do everything in cents!

```
sum = int(input("Your text") * 100)
cents = [2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
coins = []

for i in euro:
    while True:
        if i <= sum:
            coins.append(i)
            sum -= i
        else:
            break

for i in range(len(coins)):
    coins[i] /= 100

print(coins)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem related to `float` accuracy. After the calculation, I get:

```
sum == 0.009999999999999133
```

i.e. slightly *less* than one Euro cent (note, you shouldn't call it `sum` because then you shadow the built-in `sum` function and can't use e.g. `sum(coins)` to get the total). You can fix this with a tolerance approach, replacing

```
while sum >= i:
```

with

```
while (sum - i) > -0.001: # allow for slight inaccuracy
```

Similarly, it is best to compare floats using a tolerance, instead of:

```
if a == b:
```

use

```
if abs(a - b) < tolerance:
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as was pointed out, this seems to be a rounding problem, since the algorithm (for this set of coins!) is correct. If you store the coins as integers in cents, the correct solution is calculated:

```
s = input("Bitte gebe einen Euro-Cent Betrag ein: ")
coins = []
euro = [2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

for i in euro:
    while s >= i:
        s -= i
        coins.append(i)
print coins
```

Output:

```
Bitte gebe einen Euro-Cent Betrag ein: 1779
[1000, 500, 200, 50, 20, 5, 2, 2]
```

Btw, I would recommend not to use `sum` as a variable name since it is the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

@BartoszKP pointed out that it's best to avoid using `float` and because you might end up with some nasty decimals that you won't like. So you might want to use `round`, with minimal changes to your code, you can do this:

```
sum = input("Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: ")
coins = []
euro = [20,10,5,2,1,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01]

for i in euro:
    while sum >= i:
        sum -= round(i,2)
        coins.append(i)

if sum > 0:
    coins.append(round(sum,2))

print coins
```

[out:]

```
Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: 19.99
[10, 5, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01]
```

But this is **NOT** the optimal solution since since you would want this instead ;)

```
Bitte gebe einen Euro Betrag ein: 19.99
[10, 5, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02]
```

Comment: because it's his/her homework to get the optimal solution ;) . I gave a correct solution, just not best.